# How to pass byte arrays between Java and JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, byte

I need to access SecureRandom Java Object from Javascript. My ultimate goal is to grab 4  bytes from PRNG and convert it to Javascript integer variable. According to http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html, the following two lines of Java code are supposed to do grab 4 random bytes:

```
byte bytes[] = new byte[4];
random.nextBytes(bytes);
```

My problems is that I don't know how to
 1) allocate byte array suitable for passing to Java method
 2) parse that array into integer afterwards

So far I have managed to getSeed() method which returns an array of random bytes. When I render HTML code provided below in Firefox it shows "[B@16f70a4", which appears to be a pointer or something.

```
<script>
var sprng = new java.security.SecureRandom();
random = sprng.getSeed(4);
document.write(random + "<br/>\n");
</script>
```

This makes me think that I succeed to instantiate and access Java class, but have a problem with type conversion.

Can anyone please help me to write **allocateJavaByteArray(N)** and **convertJavaByteArrayToInt(N)** to let the following code work:

```
var sprng = new java.security.SecureRandom();
var nextBytes = allocateJavaByteArray(4);
srng.nextBytes(nextBytes);
var nextInt = convertJavaByteArrayToInt(4);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What sort of weird context are you in that you can get at Java runtime from a `<script>` tag?  I think there may be some confusion afoot here.

Comment: I have tested it in Firefox 3.0 on Ubuntu. See also http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch22_03.htm

Comment: find a good JSON encoding class for java and pass only JSON as any data for javascript. BTW - I don't get how You put java in <script> tags either.

Comment: Unless you prefer to stay in denial, please consider checking the link I gave above and/or running the piece of Javascript code I have provided in the OP in a Mozilla-based browser. It does not work in IE though.

Comment: Old question, I know, but did you happen to get a solution? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: The cleanest solution appears to be to create Java applet and invoke its method from JavaScript. Other approaches are non-portable. I have posted the original question when I needed to give a customer a recommendation on how to fix the problem. But the customer has chosen to accept the security risk because they didn't want to complicate the application, so I did not prepare any PoC code. When you say you have the same problem -- is it exactly the same (you need good PRNG) or you need to convert the arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement **convertJavaByteArrayToInt** like this:

```
function convertJavaByteArrayToInt(bytes) {
  var r = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    r += (bytes[i] & 0xff) << (8 * i);
  }
  return r;
}
```

**allocateJavaByteArray** is difficult to implement, because we cannot get the **Class** of **byte**. So it's not possible to use **java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance** to create a **byte[]** instance. But here is a tricky implementation:

```
function allocateJavaByteArray(n) {
  var r = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    r += "0";
  }
  return new java.lang.String(r).getBytes();
}
```

**updated**: It seems that above code not worked in FireFox 3.6. Here is another **allocateJavaByteArray** implementation, have a try:

```
function allocateJavaByteArray(n) {
  var r = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream(4);
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    r.write(0);
  }
  return r.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your code: http://pastebin.com/UW59urTW . Unfortunately convertJavaByteArrayToInt() returns 0. I don't know if it is a conversion problem or perhaps SPRNG invocation is incorrect.

Comment: change **convertJavaByteArrayToInt(4)** to **convertJavaByteArrayToInt(nextBytes)** , you will get what you want.

Comment: Same difference, I still getting 0.I try it on Firefox 3.6.17 on Ubuntu. On what browser/platform you have it working?

Comment: There appears to be a problem with array allocation. If I try to get its length, I get "public netscape.javascript.JSException(int,java.lang.Object)" instead of expected 4. Any clue why? Here is the updated code: http://pastebin.com/fFr9rwqz

Comment: I test it by FF4.01/MacOSX. Everything is OK.

Comment: I have updated the answer and have passed the test in FireFox3.6/MacOSX. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd generate the random number on the server and pass it in the Request to the jsp.

Comment: Tony, thank you for your comment, but JSP is not relevant to my situation. Everything happens on the client side.

Comment: @abb maybe you are confusing Java and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply generate a random integer in the first place, like this:

```
var nextInt = sprng.nextInt();
```

Comment: what is the typescript service type for byte?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74467236/react-typescript-api-type-for-java-byte-image-png

Answer (score 0):

Java string is the only thing that will pass Java->JS or JS->Java without headache.

byte[] or any arry will be seen in JS as JSObject.

---

```
var sprng = new java.security.SecureRandom();
```

is

```
var foo= new java.package.SomeClass();
```

does work in Netscape/Mozilla/FF

It needs access to classes, so any java standard class or you need to load a jar and then access the class.

---

to orginal question:

1. create applet whith utility method:

   public String someStringEncodedValue(){
   return 1+"|"+2;
   }
2. include applet into the page with unique id
3. JS find applet using unique id
4. call method
5. parse string ( split by | )