# React Typescript API Type for Java byte[] image/png

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am converting this to a Typescript Service for our React web application. Below is the Original API in Java. What is the Typescript Response data type? Blob?

```
@GET
@Path("/{vendorId}/Photo}")
@Produces("image/png")
byte[] getVendorPhoto(@PathVariable long vendorId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS equivalent of Java `byte` type is a `Int8Array`. Because the Java `byte` is a signed 8-bit integer.

```
const byteArray = new Int8Array(new ArrayBuffer(arrayOfInts));
```

Comment: follow up question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74480265/react-image-createobjecturl-link-gives-error-404-not-found

Answer (score 1):

By [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)

```js
const idView = new Uint32Array(buffer, 0, 1);
const usernameView = new Uint8Array(buffer, 4, 16);
const amountDueView = new Float32Array(buffer, 20, 1);
```

Comment: so for my example above, byte[]  image/png, should I use Uint32, Float32, Unit8? what is the best option out of 3?

Comment: @mattsmith5 actually, it depends on your condition. maybe try out float32.

Comment: hi, what condition is that? what should I look out for?

Comment: @mattsmith5 based on the data stored in the buffer. AFAIK

Comment: its a byte array png, I am trying to research what array type out of the 3 is best for image pngs