# React Image: createObjectURL link gives error 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, arraybuffer

I created an ImageUrl using the following  code in React with Typescript. It made a URL, however does not show a picture image. Clicking on the URL eg "http://localhost:3003/0b4de100-d8eb-49a7-b43a-e2147310abbe" gives error below. How can I fix this ?

**Error:**

> http://localhost:3003/0b4de100-d8eb-49a7-b43a-e2147310abbe Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

**Code:**

```
 const [photoURL, setPhotoUrl] = useState<string>('');

 const pictureData = await getPatientAvatar(patientId);
 const blob = new Blob([pictureData], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
 const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 setPhotoUrl(imageUrl);

 <img src={photoUrl} />
```

**Picture in Network Tab:**

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what `pictureData` is?

Comment: its a picture of a tree @kinduser

Comment: Show us `console.log(pictureData)`

Comment: hi @kinduser I updated the picture in console tab

Comment: @mattsmith5 Consider showing us more of your code. If the issue is not in the snippet you pasted, then no one here will be able to help you. For instance, what is `photoUrl` and `setPhotoUrl`?

Comment: hi @Berthur its a state variable, I just added a declaration in the code sample

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a data URL instead? If so, try the function from this post to convert a Blob to a Data URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150333/html5-javascript-dataurl-to-blob-blob-to-dataurl/30407959#30407959

Comment: Are you using create-react-app or is there any other build tool like Vite? I'll share the links for the both so that you should take a look at them or ping me with the one you use in order to get an answer as a broader topic. Here is for the [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html) and here is for [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL created by invoking [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) is a [blob URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30864573/438273) and its [protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/protocol) is always `blob:`.

The URL that you showed in your question is not a blob URL created using that method because its protocol is `http:`.

I've included a working example in a code snippet below. It will create an object URL from image blob data, and then render the URL as a string, also using it as the source for rendering an actual image. You can use the code as a model to reproduce success.

```html
<style>.avatar { height: 150px; width: 150px; }</style>
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.20.4/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

// This Stack Overflow snippet uses UMD modules
const {StrictMode, useEffect, useState} = React;

// Since the Stack Overflow code snippet doesn't have access to your server,
// here is a function for fetching your example image data as a blob
async function fetchImageBlob (): Promise<Blob> {
  const response = await fetch('https://i.imgur.com/uSvshvJ.jpg');
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Response not OK');
  return response.blob();
}

function App (): React.ReactElement {
  const [objUrl, setObjUrl] = useState<string | undefined>();
  
  useEffect(() => void (async () => {
    if (objUrl) return;
    const blob = await fetchImageBlob();
    const oUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    setObjUrl(oUrl);
  })(), [objUrl]);

  return objUrl
    ? (
      <div>
        <pre><code>{objUrl}</code></pre>
        <img className="avatar" src={objUrl}></img>
      </div>
    )
    : (<div>Loading image...</div>);
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);

reactRoot.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

</script>
```

[Code in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAEQHkBZAXzjSghDgHIozKBaJNgHpyOYCgB2MDgG4AUKEixEqTLnxFSFGABo4AZRhRglOhFS6sBFAFE0aFJQtWDGGCiYs2nblpmzZgoL6wOLkKHAwABbhLuQA1nA0AG4oUGg4EADucORm4QTiwGBgKPACKAUc8JEYKXAUYQREMBBwAJ4QWFBwVlApUNoBQdHccMBEGMxYoTDAEOLM0Myl5JEhAObtnd0oAB4Y4DjhoBjr4Uiuk4T1cABGGbeyhG2hUzNzC-YwqwCSIKcoABCDzgAAoAJQALjgAAVWCBxigADzAiC3AB8iFkcBy8wI8G4BEg4iscAAvPVMhhgPAvqtQRxIjAYGACJDAsAAHSgdZdTm5ECCLB6JIESJJABSnIAVmB1hxwXIccA0GCAISE4lWTkQOLgiKRVjZcQobLWKCsKAM0hEvHhcQQeA0ADSCqVcG4MC6C01ds59zRELkDH8aGmlA+cAAgsUwVCSDwYJzNJRrEcQBJ4AhsbiSfAANpo6UAVSgOF0VhgNFuJbLAF1yXBLCgXG4kfijOJNgAfJviFQhFBIdFBnM55u2eyUUEQ8mYpIQYBIMHPV6zsmY7M45Wq0FF0s4fWe73unG5PN3EEUjBUmnLb6RP4A1G3Ufb3P4uAQA+N4vEAAy-I+G41bSg4MB-v+oIBrcio5jilagQee4HnBOIMOCEK6IWNYHnWcE5seUALPuZbwXAAD8YLkTiSJIMASTojR25ImA3DokiuSoOiCCkTgDBIsIeQcYIbEoEx77vkiPI5DghAEAAcgcKBkgARLUlxQKpPRQOQZK8bhZYMCJPISZJgn0Yx5HguR0KgnRDHov+EAYPRXZjP8Zyct5FmOXBIayOen4+JQxAQI6jYptQ9BAWQbhhY6oICOQWAZpInJnDAaYoGlMCAm0PxIAyrCOgqaoESFMAJUm3D9qkoI5kiBhGCYwnkUiMZgHAghmYJzXGDApjcbIcFAA)